# xcode 6.1 GM Seed Hang and stops responding

Tags: xcode, freeze

I'm working on a project and a few seconds after I open a project and try to start working, I get the spinning ball and xcode stops responding completely. I tried restarting the comptuer and everything. I'm running xcode version 6.1 GM Seed with Mac OSx 10.9.4 on a Mac Mini. Mainly hang when try to do something with Views and LayoutSubviews. Is there anything I can do to fix this?